# What kind of action is exactly to done a quickdraw shield?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, shield, move-action

The quickdraw shield text is a bit confusing

> Benefit: If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you may don or put away a quickdraw shield as **a swift action combined with a regular move**. If you have the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, you can draw a light or one-handed weapon with one hand and a quickdraw shield with the other in the time it would normally take you to draw one weapon. If you have the Quick Draw feat, you may don or put away a quickdraw shield as a free action.

What does the "regular move" part mean? Do you need to use the move action as part of donning the shield? In that case, donning a regular shield is already a  move action, so what's the benefit? Does it just mean that you can still make a move action with this shield, or does it mean that you *must* make a move action and can't take a full-round attack?

To give a specific example, I have a character with gloves of storing. In the gloves is a 1H weapon. I want to be able to:

1. Sheath my 2H weapon (move action)
2. Don the quickdraw shield (swift action)
3. Bring my 1H weapon from my gloves (free action)

And also reverse that:

1. Stow my 1H with the gloves (free action)
2. Stow the quickdraw (swift action)
3. Draw my 2H weapon (move action)

Comment: Whew, the answer was more tricky than expected. Thanks for making me learn about drawing shields in PF.

Comment: No thank you. It was quite thorough and helpful, and makes sense. The shield seems largely built for having quickdraw, where you would be able to sheathe as a move, but then draw as a free action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you can don the shield as a swift action, while you are using a move action to move. If you do not move, drawing a quickdraw shield is still a move action.

The phrasing follows the equivalent part about [drawing a weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Draw-or-Sheathe-a-Weapon):

> If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you may draw a weapon as a free action combined with a regular move.

Note that this "move-and-equip"-rule also applies to [readying a shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Ready-or-Drop-a-Shield):

> If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you can ready or drop a shield as a free action combined with a regular move.

This makes quickdraw shields seem incredibly useless.

However, even though it is not explicitly stated, I believe these two things are mutually exclusive, i.e. you draw either a (single) weapon, or ready a (single) shield as part of a single move action. This is backed up by the part about Two-Weapon Fighting allowing to draw two weapons at once, as a shield can also be (used as) a weapon.

The quickdraw shield then has the advantage of enabling you to move whilst drawing a weapon and strapping on your shield, at the expense of your swift action.

---

As to your example, a quickdraw shield does not help you in the first part, since you are not drawing a weapon as part of a move action. In any case: you can't attack in that round, since you will need to move (using your converted standard action, as you have already used your move action) in order to draw the shield as a free (or swift) action. In your notation:

1. Sheathe 2H weapon (move action)
2. Move, while donning the quickdraw shield (2nd move action & free action)
3. Bring 1H weapon from my gloves (free action)

The other way around, the quickdraw shield DOES help. You can put away your shield as a swift action AND draw your 2H-weapon as a free action during the same move, which leaves you with a standard action to clobber your foe.

1. Stow 1H with the gloves (free action)
2. Move, while stowing the quickdraw shield and drawing 2H weapon (move action, swift action & free action)

Comment: *Quickdraw shields* can also be **put away** as a swift+regular move, which makes them not useless at all in certain cases.